# Get column data from multiple tables dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, information-schema

I have a list of tables for which I need to search if a single data point (`userid`) exists in any one table.

The following query gives list of tables with column `userid`:

```
select table_name
from information_schema.columns
where column_name = 'userid'
```

I would like to do a dynamic `Select userid from table_1...table_n` to show all the `userid`s across these tables.

Expected psuedo query:

```
select userid, table_name from table_1...table_n
where userid = 'search'
```

Comment: So you're already half way there, what's stopping you from constructing your desired query?

Comment: @Stu I don't know how to construct it. I have 50+ tables and the only approach I can think of is to create a script in some other language that creates a `UNION` query for this task. There should be a better way I hope

Comment: It seems like you might want to do some research on dynamic SQL. Then you can use the constructs of T-SQL to build the required SQL string from the information you have obtained and then run it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UNION ALL` for this. (Avoid plain `UNION` because it does extra work to deduplicate its result set.)  Yes, it makes for an unpleasantly verbose query.

You'll end up writing code to create a query that looks like this.

```sql
SELECT userid, 'table_1' table_name FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT userid, 'table_2' table_name FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT userid, 'table_3' table_name FROM table3
...
```

There *is* some good news buried here.  If you create a view containing this dirty great query ...

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_userids 
SELECT userid, 'table_1' table_name FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT userid, 'table_2' table_name FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT userid, 'table_3' table_name FROM table3
```

then do queries against the view like

```sql
SELECT userid FROM all_userids WHERE table_name = 'table_2'
```

the query optimizer knows what you're doing and avoids reading all the tables.

You can write a program to query the information_schema and generate this dirty great UNION ALL query. It's probably easiest to do that in a host language like Java / C# / php / whatever.

But you can also do it in SQL.  Figure out how to write a query whose output is a query. Something like this might work. It uses [STRING_AGG(val, separator)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to generate the various SELECTs with UNION ALL between them.  It then uses [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to run the query.

```
DECLARE @q NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT N'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_userids ' +
       STRING_AGG 
         (N'SELECT userid, ''' + table_name + N''' table_name FROM ' + table_name , 
          N' UNION ALL ') + N';'
  INTO @q
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE column_name = 'userid';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @q;
```

This is not, repeat not, debugged.

Comment: I want this to work without typing table names in the query. Something like the table names is fetched directly from the query I have and get used. Sorry if I was not clear. Not sure if it is possible