# SQL query to feed second query

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, sql-server-2019

I'm *trying* to work out if it's possible to combine two (or more) queries together into one, where the second one requires a table name and "where" value from the first.

This is the first query which returns the "where" value and table name for the subsequent queries:

```
select table_id, r_table, target FROM S_QOS_DATA
where robot = 'hostname'
AND qos='QOS_CPU_MULTI_USAGE'
```

which returns the following table:

| table_id | r_table | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1332070 | RN_QOS_DATA_0073 | hostname-0 |
| 1332071 | RN_QOS_DATA_0074 | hostname-1 |
| 1332072 | RN_QOS_DATA_0075 | hostname-2 |

I've then been manually running the following query with each of the above values:

```
select sampletime, samplevalue, 'hostname-0' as target
FROM RN_QOS_DATA_0073
where table_id = 1332070
```

which returns the following (well, 4 rows of the 44,500):

| sampletime | samplevalue | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-26 00:00:42.000 | 45.59 | hostname-0 |
| 2022-01-26 00:01:42.000 | 39.66 | hostname-0 |
| 2022-01-26 00:02:42.000 | 44.54 | hostname-0 |
| 2022-01-26 00:03:42.000 | 42.23 | hostname-0 |

The next query will look like this:

```
select sampletime, samplevalue, 'hostname-1' as target
FROM RN_QOS_DATA_0074
where table_id = 1332071
```

then

```
select sampletime, samplevalue, 'hostname-2' as target
FROM RN_QOS_DATA_0075
where table_id = 1332072
```

and so on, and so on.

I've been searching through here for nested queries for the past couple of hours, but I'm not sure if that's the correct terminology as none of the examples I can find show a list of results being used as the table name.

My ultimate goal is to run a single query that returns a table like this:

| sampletime | samplevalue | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-26 00:00:42.000 | 45.59 | hostname-0 |
| 2022-01-26 00:01:42.000 | 39.66 | hostname-0 |
| 2022-01-26 00:02:42.000 | 44.54 | hostname-0 |
| 2022-01-26 00:03:42.000 | 42.23 | hostname-0 |
| 2022-01-27 00:00:42.000 | 45.02 | hostname-1 |
| 2022-01-27 00:01:42.000 | 42.11 | hostname-1 |
| 2022-01-27 00:02:42.000 | 38.12 | hostname-1 |
| 2022-01-27 00:03:42.000 | 40.69 | hostname-1 |
| 2022-01-26 00:00:42.000 | 53.28 | hostname-2 |
| 2022-01-26 00:01:42.000 | 45.10 | hostname-2 |
| 2022-01-26 00:02:42.000 | 45.97 | hostname-2 |
| 2022-01-26 00:03:42.000 | 47.60 | hostname-2 |

If it's possible, I'd be so grateful if someone could push me in the right direction with the proper terminology.

Comment: This is called [tag:dynamic-sql]. That's a fancy name for writing a program that writes a query. It's necessary because ordinary SQL does not allow using coliumn values for object (database, table, column) names. Here's a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71258720/get-column-data-from-multiple-tables-dynamically/71258886#71258886

Comment: I stringly suggest you put all those tables into one table, then you don't need dynamic SQL

Comment: When you are start running into serious logical issues trying to put a query together it is almost always a sign that the design is less than ideal. That is certainly the case here.

Comment: Thanks guys. Unfortunately I have no control over the database schema or design... it's being populated by a proprietry app. Looks like I'm off to learn some dynamic sql!

Comment: how many of those numbered tables do you have? I would actually write a query that will insert the data from all those tables into one, then create reports from that temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

A work colleage managed to get this working, but as it was their first attempt at Dynamic SQL - they're not sure if its efficient or "correct".

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @robot as NVARCHAR(MAX);
set @robot = 'hostname';
select TOP 1 @table=r_table FROM S_QOS_DATA where robot =@robot AND qos='QOS_CPU_MULTI_USAGE';
set @sql = N'select points.sampletime as time, points.samplevalue, hosts.target
FROM S_QOS_DATA AS hosts 
JOIN '+@table+' AS points 
ON hosts.table_id = points.table_id AND hosts.robot='+ CHAR(39)+@robot+ CHAR(39)+' AND qos=''QOS_CPU_MULTI_USAGE'' AND points.sampletime 
ORDER BY points.sampletime';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Any advice or recommendations would be appreciated!

Comment: use quotename around `@table` and (ii) pass `@robot` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of `DynamicQuery`.

Here it is.

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl_master(table_Id INT, r_table VARCHAR(100), target VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO Tbl_master VALUES (1332070, 'RN_QOS_DATA_0073','hostname-0')
INSERT INTO Tbl_master VALUES (1332071, 'RN_QOS_DATA_0074','hostname-1')
INSERT INTO Tbl_master VALUES (1332072, 'RN_QOS_DATA_0075','hostname-2')

CREATE TABLE RN_QOS_DATA_0073 (table_Id INT, SampleTime DATETIME, SampleValue NUMERIC (10,2), target VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO RN_QOS_DATA_0073 VALUES (1332070, '2022-01-26 00:00:42.000', 1.1,'hostname-0')
INSERT INTO RN_QOS_DATA_0073 VALUES (1332070, '2022-01-26 00:01:42.000', 2.1,'hostname-0')
INSERT INTO RN_QOS_DATA_0073 VALUES (1332070, '2022-01-26 00:02:42.000', 3.1,'hostname-0')

CREATE TABLE RN_QOS_DATA_0074 (table_Id INT, SampleTime DATETIME, SampleValue NUMERIC (10,2), target VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO RN_QOS_DATA_0074 VALUES (1332071, '2022-01-27 00:00:42.000', 1.2,'hostname-1')
INSERT INTO RN_QOS_DATA_0074 VALUES (1332071, '2022-01-27 00:01:42.000', 2.2,'hostname-1')
INSERT INTO RN_QOS_DATA_0074 VALUES (1332071, '2022-01-27 00:02:42.000', 3.2,'hostname-1')

CREATE TABLE RN_QOS_DATA_0075 (table_Id INT, SampleTime DATETIME, SampleValue NUMERIC (10,2), target VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO RN_QOS_DATA_0075 VALUES (1332072, '2022-01-28 00:00:42.000', 1.3,'hostname-2')
INSERT INTO RN_QOS_DATA_0075 VALUES (1332072, '2022-01-28 00:01:42.000', 2.3,'hostname-2')
INSERT INTO RN_QOS_DATA_0075 VALUES (1332072, '2022-01-28 00:02:42.000', 3.3,'hostname-2')
```

Dynamically form the execution SQL script:

```
DECLARE @ExecQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ExecQuery = STRING_AGG('SELECT sampletime, samplevalue,'''+target+''' as Target FROM '+r_table+' WHERE table_Id = '+ CAST(table_Id AS VARCHAR),' UNION ALL ')
FROM Tbl_master

EXEC (@ExecQuery)
```

The output is

```
sampletime              samplevalue Target
2022-01-26 00:00:42.000 1.10        hostname-0
2022-01-26 00:01:42.000 2.10        hostname-0
2022-01-26 00:02:42.000 3.10        hostname-0
2022-01-27 00:00:42.000 1.20        hostname-1
2022-01-27 00:01:42.000 2.20        hostname-1
2022-01-27 00:02:42.000 3.20        hostname-1
2022-01-28 00:00:42.000 1.30        hostname-2
2022-01-28 00:01:42.000 2.30        hostname-2
2022-01-28 00:02:42.000 3.30        hostname-2
```